# Is there a term for this phenomenon?

Tags: terminology, syntactic-analysis

I've been wondering for a while now whether there is a word (or linguistic term) that specifically refers to an instance where a clause can be part of either the clause before it or the clause after it.

One such example would be P!nk's song "Walk of Shame":

> I shouldn't have let 'em take my keys, take my keys
>   They left me here
>   With too much beer.
>   My friends, they hung me out to dry.
>   **It's not my fault, and that's why**
>   I'm doin' the walk of shame

The specific instance is in bold, and my thought process is as follows:

1. > My friends, they hung me out to dry; **it's not my fault and that's why**.

She could be saying that her **friends** are why she's doing the walk of shame. i.e. *It's not my fault because my friends hung me out to dry.*

2. > **It's not my fault, and that's why** I'm doing the walk of shame.

She could be saying that **it's not her fault** that she's doing the walk of shame.

I know it's not the best example because both 1) and 2) are similar in meaning, but nonetheless, is there a term for this phenomenon? I also know that 2) is likely the intended structure, but it does provoke thought if you ignore the full stop after "dry".

Comment: Any possible way you could give a clearer example?

Comment: @Silenus I will if I come across one; I can't think of any others off the top of my head.

Comment: This page has an example of *ambiguous placement* of modifiers: http://www.ucalgary.ca/uofc/eduweb/grammar/course/sentence/2_6b.htm

Answer (score 0):

I agree it's not the best example, because you had to change the punctuation to make your point. (Also, I'm not convinced Pink's lyrics merit close scrutiny, but that's a different discussion.)

I think the term you're looking for might be *ambiguity* or *ambiguous phrasing*. There's a good description of ambiguity here:

http://literarydevices.net/ambiguity/

> Ambiguity or fallacy of ambiguity is a word, phrase, or statement
>   which contains more than one meaning.
>
> Ambiguous words or statements lead to vagueness and confusion, and
>   shape the basis for instances of unintentional humor.

A section of lyrics or prose containing logic that is confusing or vague can be referred to as *ambiguous statements* or *ambiguous phrasing*.

Comment: Man eating shark!